# spock not able to find classpath

Tags: java, unit-testing, gradle, spock

Hell All

I have a simple(very first) test case written using Spock and gradle. Following is my specification

```
package catalog

import spock.lang.Specification

class ItemkeySpec extends Specification{
    def "HashMap accepts null key"() {
        setup:
            def map = new HashMap()

        when:
            map.put(null, "elem")

        then:
            notThrown(NullPointerException)
    }
    def "Initialize itemkeys"(){
        when:
            Root root = new Root()
            def init = catalog.itemkey.getItemKeyValueFromName(root,"ApuId")
        then:
            init == true
    }
}
```

While my very first test case works perfectly because it does not refer to any of my product packages(under main/src/java) but for the second test case I get an error like following

**Seems like the main/src/java is not added to class path**

```
No such property: catalog for class: catalog.ItemkeySpec
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: catalog for class: catalog.ItemkeySpec
    at catalog.ItemkeySpec.Initialize itemkeys(ItemkeySpec.groovy:22)
```

Am i missing something in the build.gradle? 
I have already added the following in it.

```
sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8
apply plugin: 'groovy'
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'idea'
compileJava.options.encoding = 'ISO-8859-1'
apply plugin: 'war'
dependencies {

    testCompile(
                'junit:junit:4.12',
                'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.4.4',
                'org.spockframework:spock-core:1.0-groovy-2.4'
        )

        testRuntime(
                'com.athaydes:spock-reports:1.2.7',

        )

}
```

Comment: What is on line 22 in ItemkeySpec.groovy? There is something wrong with propert catalog

Comment: @Hrabosch `def init = catalog.itemkey.getItemKeyValueFromName(root,"ApuId")`

Comment: And where is catalog defined? I am not able to find it

Comment: @Hrabosch catalog is name of the java package which is under src/main/java

Comment: Are you using Grails? What kind of method is getItemKeyValueFromName? Your own method or GORM?

Comment: You cannot call methods on Java packages as far as I know. catalog.itemkey is obviously wrong if catalog is just a package and nothing else.

Comment: Catalog is the package name itemkey is the class name. This is a 10-15 year old class which I am trying  to test